# If $H\unlhd G$ is abelian with $H\not\subseteq Z(G)$, there exists $g\in G$ such that conjugation by $g$ is not an inner automorphism of $H$?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

I am reading *Abstract Algebra: 3rd Edition* by Dummit and Foote. On page 134, example 1, it says:

> A group $G$ is abelian if and only if every inner automorphism is trivial. If $H$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is not contained in $Z(G)$, then there is some $g\in G$ such that conjugation by $g$ restricted to $H$ is not an inner automorphism of $H$.

I'm trying to prove both of these statements, and I'm having trouble understanding the second one.

The first statement is pretty easy:
$$\begin{align*}
G\text{ is abelian}&\iff gh=hg\text{ for all }g,h\in G\\
&\iff ghg^{-1}=h\text{ for all }g,h\in G\\
&\iff\sigma_g(h)=h\text{ for all }\sigma_g\in \text{Inn}(G), h\in H\\
&\iff \sigma_g = \text{id}_{\text{Aut}(G)}\text{ for all }\sigma_g\in \text{Inn}(G).
\end{align*}$$

(Is this correct?)

Next, I suppose I don't understand the second statement. What I understand it to mean is that if $H$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$ and $H\not\subseteq Z(G)$, then there exists $g\in G$ such that $\sigma_g:h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$ is not an automorphism of $H$.

What I've tried:

Since $H\unlhd G$, we have that $h_1g=gh_2$ for some $h_1, h_2\in H$, for all $g\in G$.

Then $h_1 = gh_2g^{-1}=\sigma_g(h_2)$.

This doesn't seem like it gets me anywhere, since it just shows that for some of the elements $h$ of $H$, we have that $\sigma_g(h)\in H$.

This leads me to take an arbitrary $\sigma_g(h)$ ($g\in G, h\in H$ are arbitrary).

But then $\sigma_g(h) = ghg^{-1} = gg^{-1}h' = h'\in H$ for some $h'\in H$ (by normality), so clearly $\sigma_g$ always maps elements in $H$ to elements in $H$.

Also, $\sigma_g(h_1h_2) = gh_1h_2g^{-1} = gh_1g^{-1}gh_2g^{-1} = \sigma_g(h_1)\sigma_g(h_2)$ so $\sigma_g$ is always a homomorphism from $H$ to $H$ (when restricted to $H$).

What am I missing? Am I misunderstanding the statement? When is $\sigma_g$ ever *not* an inner automorphism? How do I use the fact that $H\not\subseteq Z(G)$?

Comment: Furthermore, if $gh_1g^{-1}=gh_2g^{-1}$ then $h_1=h_2$ so $\sigma_g$ is injective, and for all $h\in H$, $h = gg^{-1}h = gh'g^{-1} = \sigma_g(h')$ for some $h'\in H$ by normality, so it seems $\sigma_g$ is an isomorphism after all. Now I'm really confused...

Comment: It doesn't say that if $H$ is normal and abelian but $H\not\subseteq Z(G)$ then there is a $g\in G$ such that $h\longmapsto ghg^{-1}$ is not an automorphism of $H$, it says that there is a $g$ such that this is not an **inner** automorphism of $H$. But that is essentially the same as saying that it is not the identity automorphism of $H$, by the first part.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the book defines "Conjugation by $g$ is called an *inner automorphism* of $G$". Is the map $h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$ not conjugation by $g$?

Comment: But it is not an inner automorphism **of $\mathbf{H}$** unless $g\in H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin forgive me, now I'm more confused than before. From what I understand, an automorphism of $H$ is simply an isomorphism from $H$ to $H$. We have shown that with a domain restricted to $H$, $\sigma_g$ satisfies this definition. Why does it matter where $g$ comes from?

Comment: If we use $\sigma_g$ to denote conjugation by $g$ as an element of $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$, and we let $s_h$ to denote the element of $\mathrm{Inn}(H)$ that is conjugation by $h\in H$, the problem asks you to prove that there exists a $g\in G$ such that for every $h\in H$, $(\sigma_g)|_H\neq s_h$.

Comment: Look at the definition of "inner automorphism" again: it has to be **inner**, that is, it has to be defined by an element of $G$. The inner automorphism of $G$ are the elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ that are in the image of the morphism $\sigma\colon G\to\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ given by $g\mapsto \sigma_g$. For $H$, the inner automorphisms of $H$ are the elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ that are given by conjugation by elements of $H$. That's the definition of "inner automorphism".

Comment: Makes sense! I suppose I should have made the mental correspondence that "...is an inner automorphism of $H$" is equivalent to "...is an element of $\text{Inn}(H)$". Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part has a couple of slight errors: your first few implications have $h,g\in G$, but your last two have $h\in H$. Remember: you are trying to prove that $G$ is abelian if and only if every inner automorphism of $G$ is trivial. There is no $H$ yet. So you may want to change those $g$ and $h$ to $x$ and $y$ to avoid confusion. And it should be $\mathrm{id}_G$, not $\mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Aut}(G)}$: the function is the identity automorphism of $G$, not of the automorphism group. So it should read something like the following (note the boldface, which is where your errors are):

$$\begin{align*}
G\text{ is abelian}&\iff xy=yx\text{ for all }x,y\in G\\
&\iff xyx^{-1}=y\text{ for all }x,y\in G\\
&\iff\sigma_x(y)=y\text{ for all }\sigma_x\in \text{Inn}(G), y\in \textbf{G}\\
&\iff \sigma_x = \textbf{id}_{\mathbf{G}}\text{ for all }\sigma_x\in \text{Inn}(G).
\end{align*}$$

As I noted in the comments, you are misinterpreting the second part. What it says is: assume that $H$ is normal and abelian, and that $H\not\subset Z(G)$. Then there exists a $g\in G$ such that $\sigma_g|_H$ is not an inner automorphism *of $H$*; that is, there does not exist an $h\in H$ such that $\sigma_g|_H = \sigma_h$, where $\sigma_h\in\mathrm{Inn}(H)$. Or equivalently, that there does not exist an $h\in H$ such that for every $x\in H$, $gxg^{-1}=hxh^{-1}$.

> We have $h_1g=gh_2$ for *some* $h_1,h_2\in H$, for all $g\in G$.

This is not correctly phrased. What is true is that for every $g\in G$ and for every $h_1\in H$, there exists an $h_2\in H$, which may depend on $h_1$ and on $g$, such that $h_1g=gh_2$. It is not just "some $h_1,h_2$", and the pair may not work for **all** $g$.

What you know is that because $H$ is normal, then for every $g\in G$ we have $gHg^{-1}=H$. So $\sigma_g(H)=H$. That means that $\sigma_g|_H$ is an automorphism of $H$.

To distinguish the inner automorphisms of $G$ from those of $H$, let us use $\sigma_g\colon G\to G$ to denote the ones that are inner automorphisms of $G$, and let us use $s_h\colon H\to H$ to denote the inner automorphisms of $H$; note that we must have $h\in H$. We know that $\sigma_g|_H\in\mathrm{Aut}(H)$. The question is: will it be in $\mathrm{Inn}(H)$? Does there exist an $h\in H$ such that $\sigma_g|_H=s_h$?

That would require that for every $x\in H$,
$$\begin{align*}
\sigma_g(x) &= s_h(x)\\
gxg^{-1} &= hxh^{-1}.
\end{align*}$$
Now, if $H$ is abelian, then $hxh^{-1}= hh^{-1}x = x$ (or, by the first part, we know that $s_h=\mathrm{id}_H$). So that would require that for every $x\in H$, $gxg^{-1}=x$; or equivalently, that for every $x\in H$, $gx=xg$.

So, I wonder if the fact that $H\not\subset Z(G)$ means that we can find some $g$ for which this does *not* happen?

Comment: Excellent answer. Yes, for the first part, $h\in H$ was in fact a typo. Everything you said makes perfect sense. Since $H\not\subseteq Z(G)$, we know that there exists $g\in G$ with $gx\neq xg$, and so the result follows. Thank you again!

Comment: @iatewalrus: Careful: since $H\not\subseteq Z(G)$, we know there exists $h\in H$ such that $h\notin Z(G)$. That means that there exists a $g\in G$ (which may depend on $h$) such that $gh\neq hg$. So you want to be careful with your quantifiers and with the order of the quantifiers.